# Show pipenv virtualenv in PS1

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, ps1, pipenv

[Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) is a relatively new packaging tool that encompasses "Pipfile, Pip, and Virtualenv". I have made changes to simplify my PS1 in `.bashrc` but now find that I need my PS1 to tell me when I am using my virtualenv.

Current PS1:

```
PS1='\w $ '
```

From the below, you can see my prompt script does nothing to tell me about whether I'm using a virtual environment:

```
~ $ cd workspace/myproject/
~/workspace/myproject $ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment. Type 'exit' or 'Ctrl+D' to return.
~/workspace/marcus_project $
```

I too often screw up my `PS1` and was hoping for a simple fix to have the prompt in the virtualenv show up like so: `(my-env) ~ $`.

Answer (score 5):

Per [the docs](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#automatic-loading-of-env), create a file called `.env` in your project.  Give it the contents

```
export PS1='(myenv) \w $ '
```

or whatever you want.  `pipenv shell` will load it.

<sup>(Note: I haven't tried `pipenv` myself.  Today I learned it exists! :) )</sup>

#### Take 2

If your `.bashrc` or `.profile` (or other startup files) set `PS1`, you can hack it.

- Put `export PIPENV_PS1='(myenv) \w $ '` in your `.env`.  (The name `PIPENV_PS1` isn't anything special — I just picked something I thought made sense.)
- At the end of your `.bashrc`, add:

  ```
  if [[ $PIPENV_PS1 ]]; then
      export PS1="$PIPENV_PS1"
  fi
  ```

That way your `.bashrc` will copy the value you have set in `.env`.

Comment: Hmm this didn't seem to do anything. Is it possible that PS1 in my bashrc overrides `.env`

Answer (score 3):

If you have virtualenv installed this behaviour come out of the box in pipenv.
What I did have some trouble with was that the pipenv shell messed up my custom PS1 I had defined. I'm answering here because when googling, this was the question that resembled my problem the most.

To fix this I had to go to `vim ~/.virtualenvs/<name of the env>/bin/activate`.
Here I changed the code where it defines the PS1 for the one I had in my `bash_profile`. The PS1 pipenv shell is now using the PS1 inside the `if [ "x(data-load) " != x ] ; then` statement.

I'm sure this can be achieved in a better way instead of redefining the PS1 in the file, and using the one in `.bash_profile` but didn't want to waste more time with this.

```
...

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then
    # add this line to get original PS1 prompt
    PS1=ORIGINAL PS1 in .bash_profile
    if [ "x(data-load) " != x ] ; then
        # here add the name of the virtual env, and some color if in the mood
        PS1="\[\033[39m\](myenv) ${PS1-}"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) ${PS1-}"
    fi
    export PS1
fi

...
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It's a shame we cannot set an environment variable which causes activate to ignore setting or overwritting `PS1` in our shell. I am using a custom prompt for git, and this just blows it away.